# Why is my DSLR taking duplicate pictures?

Tags: file-management, sdcard, duplicates

My Nikon d7000 is making an exact duplicate of each picture taken.  I have 2 of every picture on my sd card. How do I stop this?

Comment: Do you hear the shutter twice? Or are you saying you get 2 files per shutter-actuation?

Comment: My wife has a Nikon d7200 and I think I just ran into this issue. We are trying to use PhotoMatch and every time we clicked a shot, TWO of the exact same image and filename were getting imported causing an error message. I "fixed" it by removing 1 of the 2 SD cards. We usually have 2 SD cards installed. So, I'm not exactly sure why it's a problem. We have 2 other cameras working fine. I suspect there is a setting. I'm going to do some more digging. I had hoped this thread would help, but don't see anything to try. Also, FWIW, we tried to fix it by doing "jpeg only" but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 26):

Have you checked file extensions? You might have your camera set in the RAW+JPEG storing mode, producing both .JPG and .NEF file for each shot, showing the same thumbnail for both of them. Also many image viewers would show both of them.

Solution: Turn off RAW+JPEG mode and use JPEG only mode.

Check page 85 of the [Nikon D7000 manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/D7000_EN.pdf) - *Image Recording Options*
(or page 64 in [Nikon D700 manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D700_en.pdf) - *Image Qualit*y in case this is your camera - you've mentioned both models).

Comment: Or use RAW only mode...

Answer (score 3):

I found my D7000 was doing this in timer re is a setting where you can select how many photos you want the camera to take when it's on a timer.. I fixed it by going int the settings for the self-timer and Changing the number of shots to 1

Answer (score 1):

It could be the RAW+JPEG mode as mentioned earlier.
In that case I'd leave it as is.
RAW = Good for editing and stuff - Think old school negatives
JPEG = Good for quickly putting pics on Facebook etc - think of old school prints
I would just set the Jpeg to a low resolution because you won't need the extra detail for editing because you'll have the Raw files to work with.

It could also be the camera bracketing the photos, so I'd look into that too.
The photos would be slightly lighter/darker though.

Answer (score -3):

Wrong wrong wrong....... Raw+jpg only takes ONE photo. The camera then stores the raw and the jpg file. They saw has a built in jpg for viewing. The camera stores these separately when set to store both.

Comment: Hi Frankie, did you mean to post this as an answer, or as a comment/suggested edit to the existing answer? As you post currently stands it doesn't seem to answer the question "*Why is my DSLR taking duplicate pictures?*". Could you be so kind to [edit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/121127/edit) your answer such that it does answer the question? Thanks!

Comment: Downvoted: It doesn't seem like you're answering the original question, but it doesn't seem to be commenting any other answer either. Regardless, you're not incorrect, but I downvoted you because of the tone of the answer. Starting your first post with "Wrong wrong wrong..." isn't a constructive way to participate in the community, IMO.